# Spark : Kafka consumer getting data as base64 encoded strings even though Producer does not explictly encode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying out a simple example to publish data to Kafka and consume it using Spark.

Here is the Producer code:

```
var kafka_input = spark.sql("""
SELECT CAST(Id AS STRING) as key, 
       to_json(
               named_struct(
                             'Id', Id,                             
                             'Title',Title                           
                           )
              ) as value 
FROM offer_data""")

kafka_input.write
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
          .option("topic", topicName)
          .save()
```

I verified that `kafka_input`has json string for value and the a number casted as string for key.

Here is the consumer code:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
  .option("subscribe", topicName)
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

df.take(50)
display(df)
```

The data I receive on the consumer side is base64 encoded string.

[image]

How do I decode the value in Scala?
Also, this read statement is not flushing these records from the Kafka queue. I am assuming this is because I am not sending any ack signal back to Kafka. IS that correct? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you show the output?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my usage of SelectExpr..It does nto do an in-place transofrmation..it returns the transformed data.
Fix:

```
df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

display(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
df.foreach(row => {
  val key = row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("key")
  val value = row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")
  println(scala.io.Source.fromBytes(key,"UTF-8").mkString)
  println(scala.io.Source.fromBytes(value,"UTF-8").mkString)
})
```